# TextView displaying one char per line

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm having a problem whereby a string in textview is displaying each character on seperate lines. My code is as below. I am hoping to show the text on one line.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sectionPicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="AM"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberPicker"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How much space do you have? Is it wrapping because it has to wrap? Can you show a picture? Is there any code that is affecting this, or are you seeing the reported results in Preview in Android Studio? Based on the XML you've posted, there shouldn't be a problem, which means you need to post a lot more information if you want someone to be able to figure it out. My off-the-cuff guess is that you are laying it out in too small of a horizontal space, so it's wrapping.

Comment: make height & width of RelativeLayout to match_parent. let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your help! The problem was that like @mbm29414 suggested I had another relative layout that the above was nested in and this layout had a left/right margin that was limiting this layouts size.

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund This didn't work as the parent layout that I hadn't included was the problem (my fault not yours).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that like @mbm29414 suggested I had another relative layout that the above was nested in and this layout had a left/right margin that was limiting this layouts size. The parent layout had a horizontal margin set to 40dp. I discovered this by rotating the screen and noticing a change.